# how to compile the dblink module on centOS server(64-bit)

Tags: postgresql

I have compiled the dblink module ubder postgresql 8.2.19/contrib/dblink
in my PC(fedora 16)
but when I turn to the CentOS,it doesn't work,hints the message below:

```
gcc -m64 -O3 -funroll-loops -fargument-noalias-global -fno-omit-frame-pointer -g -finline-limit=1800 -std=gnu99  -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wpointer-arith  -Wendif-labels -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -I/home/build/builds/greenplum-db/Release-4_1_1_1-build-1_ce_051211-1820/Release-4_1_1_1-build-1_src/ext/rhel5_x86_64/include -Werror -fpic -I/home/gpadmin/greenplum-db/include -w -I. -I/home/gpadmin/greenplum-db/include/postgresql/server -I/home/gpadmin/greenplum-db/include/postgresql/internal -D_GNU_SOURCE  -I/home/build/builds/greenplum-db/Release-4_1_1_1-build-1_ce_051211-1820/Release-4_1_1_1-build-1_src/ext/rhel5_x86_64/include  -c -o dblink.o dblink.c
dblink.c:1: sorry, unimplemented: 64-bit mode not compiled in
make: *** [dblink.o] error 1
```

can anyone give some proposal?
run "which postgres"

on CentOS get: *~/greenplum-db/bin/postgres*
on Fedora get:*/usr/local/greenplum-db/bin/postgres*

Answer (score 1):

First, 8.2.19 seems very outdated version of PostgreSQL, current one is 9.1.3, consider using a newer version.

It is not safe to copy over object files from 32 to 64 bit systems and expect they will work properly. I suggest you should run:

```
make clean
make
```

in the `dblink` source folder. Also, it might happen that you need to re-configure your sources so that Makefile points to the proper libraries in case you have several PostgreSQL versions installed.

Comment: I want to use dblink in the greeplum database based on postgresql 8.2.15,so I should use the postgresql 8.2.X

Comment: Is your `greenplum`'s pg_config found first by your `PATH` settings?

Comment: $pg_config --pgxs
/usr/local/greenplum-db-4.1.0.0/lib/postgresql/pgxs/src/makefiles/pgxs.mk

Comment: Are you compiling `dblink` from the greenplum sources? Or have you downloaded it with PostgreSQL?

Comment: I download the sources of postgresql8.2.19,
run"make USE_PGXS=1 install"
and it works on my PC(fedora16 32bit),
when I turn it to our server(CentOS 64bit)
it does not work!

Comment: Could you kindly post the output of the following command for both, your Fedora and your CentOS servers: `ldd $(which postgres)`. You can update your initial post for this.

Comment: I don't understand your last comment. Is it possible to post the output of the `ldd` command above?